# What does this error mean 'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm following a tutorial to train a chatbot. However, I keep getting this error and I don't know what it means,
**line 16, in 
    last_unix = df.tail(1)['unix'].values[0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0**

Below is my code. line 16 is **last_unix = df.tail(1)['unix'].values[0]**

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

timeframes = ['2015-01']

for timeframe in timeframes:
    connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/danieldossantos/Desktop/Faisnet/RC_{}.db'.format(timeframe))
    c = connection.cursor()
    limit = 5000
    last_unix = 0
    cur_length = limit
    counter = 0
    test_done = False
    while cur_length == limit:
        df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM parent_reply WHERE unix > {} AND parent NOT NULL AND score > 0 ORDER BY unix ASC LIMIT {}".format(last_unix, limit), connection)
        last_unix = df.tail(1)['unix'].values[0]
        cur_length = len(df)
        if not test_done:
            with open("test.from", 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
                for content in df['parent'].values:
                    f.write(content+'\n')
            with open("test.to", 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
                for content in df['comment'].values:
                    f.write(content+'\n')
            test_done = True

        else:
            with open("train.from", 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
                for content in df['parent'].values:
                    f.write(content+'\n')
            with open("train.to", 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
                for content in df['comment'].values:
                    f.write(content+'\n')

        counter += 1
        if counter % 20 == 0:
            print(counter*limit, 'rows completed so far')
```

I tried adding

```
df = pd.read_sql(
            "SELECT * FROM parent_reply WHERE unix > {} AND parent NOT NULL AND parent != 'False' AND score > 0 ORDER BY unix ASC LIMIT {}".format( last_unix, limit), connection)
```

But that did nothing

I'm supposed to be getting the number of rows completed.

Comment: Do you need only count? Then directly you can write `count(*)` in query. Check `print(df.tail(1)['unix'])` may be you are not getting any data there.

Comment: Looks like there is problem with your query. Can you give more details about what you are trying to do and accordingly query can be recommended. Problem is not with the pandas.

Comment: @Abhilash Awasthi I'm following a tutorial on creating a chatbot. This is the tutorial I'm following, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tw8G8-KMRf8&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdc2k5dwtDTyT9aCja0on8j&index=7&t=0s .

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that there is no data returned when you run this `df.tail(1)['unix'].values[0]`.
It gives an empty numpy array, so there is nothing at first position or 0th index.
What you can do after the `pd.read_sql` line is -

- `print(df.shape)` to see the number of rows and columns returned by the query.
- `print(df.tail(1)['unix'])` to see the `unix` column of the last row of the dataframe and check whether it has any value or not.

Comment: I got my dataset from a torrent link, I'm not sure if that's an issue. this is the site, https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3bxlg7/i_have_every_publicly_available_reddit_comment/?st=j9udbxta&sh=69e4fee7

Comment: I got an error when doing print(df.shape) and or print(df.tail(1)['unix']) **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.from'**

Comment: @DanieldosSantos Please paste whole error in the question that you are facing now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,

> index1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

but it occurred in the line in which SQL - `pd.read_sql()` is being read, and it helped me that 
**I removed * in the SQL query, and selected specific fields**, maybe it will be useful to someone

Answer (score 0):

This could work. I believe the pandas dataframe is unable to sort the order of index.

```
df = pd.read_sql(
            "SELECT parent_reply.* FROM parent_reply WHERE unix > {} AND parent NOT NULL AND parent != 'False' AND score > 0 ORDER BY unix ASC LIMIT {}".format( last_unix, limit), connection)
```